# Bootstrap validation not working with bootstrap select

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, select

When I apply bootstrap validation on the form and already have drop downs (Select) with bootstrap chosen list.

It validates but not showing the error message from validator for the drop downs.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when we apply bootstrap dropdown to make the select list fancy and easy to use it hides the native html select and creates new with custom options.

When a native drop down is hidden it also hides the validation message too by applying the inline css property `display:none`.

So here is the quick fix for it.

```
#country {
   display: block !important;
   height: 0;
   margin-top: -14px;
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

By default set display to block and set visibility to hidden and it will work like magic.

Comment: Nice trick. by the way, I have read that margin cannot be in minus ... maybe we can use position:relative; left : -14px;

Comment: This margin is to show the error message on the right place. You can set it according to your needs.

Comment: margin can be set to a negative number, its padding that cannot be minus